# ros2 video device

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the image_tools package in ROS2, how do I set the video device if I have a usb cam for example.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297362/ros2-video-device/) by [tobinfinity](https://answers.ros.org/users/30658/tobinfinity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This package is using OpenCV to get the input of the camera (check this link for a more detailed example: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html):
https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html

The interesting part for you is:
https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/71ab3261675c1f44e1e280556d4fb323efee51f2/image_tools/src/cam2image.cpp#L153

Where the example does the init of the video capture stream if the boolean `burger_mode` is `false`.

You will need to know the device ID of the camera which should be related to the USB port number the camera is connected to.

---

Originally posted by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) with karma: 527 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0